# nginx path_info in alias environemnt

Tags: nginx, php, pathinfo

I need to get this working on nginx with php-fpm:

```
example.com/studip/dispatch.php/admin/user/
```

The Problem seems to be, that /studip isn't a subfolder under root but a alias to /usr/local/studip/public/

Here's the configuration without the (non working) path_info foo:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
    index index.php

    # Here are a few other subfolders hosted
    # ...
    # ...

    # and now studip:

    location /studip {
        alias /usr/local/studip/public/;
        index index.php;
        location ~ /studip/(.*\.php)$ {
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/www/sockets/studip.socket;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$1;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

And the fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port; 
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;

fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```

I tried it for a sub-domain where root points to /usr/local/studip/public/ and get it working with this params:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;

    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/www/sockets/www.socket;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
}
```

But I got no idea how to port this to subfolder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using rewrite rules to remove the front controller such as "index.php". You'll actually get empty PATH_INFOs... This may screw up certain frameworks such as Codeigniter. We should test for the existence of path info before setting them.

Answer (score 1):

So here's what you do:

For FCGI, DO NOT set fix_pathinfo to 0 as recommended!!  This causes an access denied status.  Instead, make sure that this cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 or is commented out in your php.ini file.

Next, use this advanced location block in place of the one that's entered into your nginx site configuration file:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

If you are not passing by socket and are passing by local IP, use this fastcgi_pass instead:

fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

In your version of the fastcgi_params, remove $document_root from in front of your SCRIPT_FILENAME variable.  It's not necessary even with a subdirectory.

That should do it.  Did it for me on Ubuntu 13.10 with PHP5.